# What is the correct way to join two dataframes using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, left-join

I'm a bit perplexed by this. Why does the code below not work as I expect?
I want the codes in 'data' to replace the NA's in 'data2'. What am I doing wrong?

(I want to use dplyr)

```
library(dplyr)

data <- data.frame(
  Name = c("Alice", "Bob", "Charlie", "David"),
  Code = c(1234, 5678, 9012, 3456)
)

data2 <- data.frame(
  Name = c("Alice", "Bob", "Charlie", "David", "Alice", "Bob"),
  Code = c(1234, 5678, 9012, 3456, NA, NA)
)


left_join(data2, data, join_by(Name))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A join will not replace any missing values. But you can achieve your desired result using an additional `mutate` step with `coalesce` to replace the `NA`s:

```r
library(dplyr, warn=FALSE)

left_join(data2, data, join_by(Name)) |>
  mutate(
    Code = coalesce(Code.x, Code.y),
    .keep = "unused"
  )
#>      Name Code
#> 1   Alice 1234
#> 2     Bob 5678
#> 3 Charlie 9012
#> 4   David 3456
#> 5   Alice 1234
#> 6     Bob 5678
```